# Use several modules in OCaml utop

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

I'm reading an OCaml project recently and I want to put the source files in the utop so I can do some experiments. 
Suppose I have two files **amodule.ml**, **bmodule.ml**. 
**bmodule.ml** will use functions defined in **amodule.ml**, for example, **bmodule** use *Amodule.anyfunction()* where *anyfunction()* is defined in **amodule.ml**.

I want to put both of them in utop:

```
#directory "/directory contain amodule.ml and bmodule.ml"
#use "amodule.ml"
#use "bmodule.ml"
```

And this doesn't work because **Amodule** is a module name base on the **amodule.ml** file and the utop don't know these things, I think.
So how I can put these files in the utop without changing the file content？

Comment: Have you tried to `cd` to the folder where amodule.ml and bmodule.ml are and then type `utop` there?

Comment: Yes.But it still doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? can you post a screenshot or full utop texts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`#use a.ml` executes every statement in a.ml just as if you had typed those statements in the toplevel directly. Thus, you do not get a `module A` defined, so your other file cannot have things like `A.foo`. If you want `module A`, you must first byte compile a.ml, and then `#load a.cmo`.

Comment: Newer versions of OCaml support `#use_mod` which should allow this without prior compilation.

Comment: The directive mentioned by @hcarty is actually `#mod_use`, and it is very handy indeed. :)

Comment: `#mod_use` is exactly the piece of the puzzle I was missing. Thank you @ShonFeder! I can't believe Real World OCaml does not mention it even once.

Comment: Anyone want some quick karma by turning `#mod_use` into a proper StackOverflow answer?

Comment: Thanks @hcarty ! `#mod_use` is exactly what I've been looking for for hours, and it answers a very basic need. Unbelievable that it's not mentioned in popular introductions to OCaml.